# How to effeciently create conditional columns arrays using Numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The objective is to create an array but by fulfilling  the condition of `(x=>y) and (y=>z)`.

One naive way but does the job is by using a nested `for loop` as shown below

```
tot_length=200
steps=0.1
start_val=0.0
list_no =np.arange(start_val, tot_length, steps)

a=np.zeros(shape=(1,3))
for x in list_no:
    for y in list_no:
        for z in list_no:
            if (x>=y) & (y>=z):
                a=np.append(a, [[x, y, z]], axis=0)
```

While no memory requirement issue was thrown, but the execution time is significantly slow.

Other approach that can be considered is by using the code [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64446483/6446053) below. Yet the proposal only able to work flawlessly as long as `tot_length` is less than `100`. More than that, memory issue arise as reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64448974/6446053)

```
tot_length=200
steps=0.1
start_val=0.0
list_no =np.arange(start_val, tot_length, steps)
arr = np.meshgrid ( *[list_no for _ in range ( 3 )] )
a = np.array(list ( map ( np.ravel, arr ) )).transpose()
num_rows, num_cols = a.shape

a_list = np.arange ( num_cols ).reshape ( (-1, 3) )
for x in range ( len ( a_list ) ):
    a=a[(a[:, a_list [x, 0]] >= a[:, a_list [x, 1]]) & (a[:, a_list [x, 1]] >= a[:, a_list [x, 2]])]
```

Appreciate for any suggestion that can balance the overall execution time as well as memory issue. I also welcome for any suggestion using Pandas if that should make thing work

To determine whether the proposed output produced the intended output, the following parameter

```
tot_length=3
steps=1
start_val=1
```

Should produce the output

```
1   1   1
2   1   1
2   2   1
2   2   2
```

Comment: For `tot_length=200`, you are looking at about 30GB memory allocation for `a`, which is not small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this work?

```
tot_length=200
steps=0.1
list_no = np.arange(0.0, tot_length, steps)
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(*[list_no for _ in range(3)], sparse=True)
a = ((x>=y) & (y>=z)).nonzero()
```

This will still use 8GB of memory for the intermediate array of booleans, but avoids repeated calls to `np.append` which are slow.

Comment: Hi Eric, I just notice, all the value in a is rounded. Is this expected? Is it because nonzero() return non floating type? For example if I set tot_length=0.3 , steps=0.1, start_val=0.1 , your proposed solution will return a round value instead of in decimal value.

Answer (score 2):

```
tot_length = 200
steps = 0.1
list_no = np.arange(0.0, tot_length, steps)

a = list()
for x in list_no:
    for y in list_no:
        if y > x:
            break

        for z in list_no:
            if z > y:
                break

            a.append([x, y, z])

a = np.array(a)
# if needed, a.transpose()
```

Comment: I don't see how this is different from OP's solution.

Comment: This avoids calling `np.append`, which is slower than using a list and converting to array at the end